# Refresh a Flatlist if data from function inside componentDidMount is changed

Tags: react-native

Good day SO.

I am a beginner in React Native so my terminology is very lacking. The project was inherited from previous programmer.

I have an async functions

```
getData = async () => {}
```

Then here:

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.getData ();
}
```

Then last is Flatlist

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.somedata}
    renderItem{({item, index}) => {}} />
```

My question is, if data is changed, how should I update my flatlist? I read that I need to add extraData but I dont know what variable should I add inside.

Note I know that componentDidMount only runs once on the first render. But I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Try `extraData={this.state.someData}` in your `FlatList`

Comment: alter getData function to fetch the data and compare it with this.state.somedata, if there if something new, update it with this.setState()

Comment: I tried the this.state.someData but it is not refreshing. Though I can see that this.state.someData is updating.